# Advice using patch within a FORALL in power apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I am developing a power app with a collection containing 2 columns(ID, Choice) I also have a SharePoint list holding more columns including those 2. On a button press, I want to iterate through the collection updating the decom status column in my SharePoint list with the value in the choice column in my collection for the corresponding Asset No/ID. I hope this makes sense and someone can give me some advice.

the code I have so far is:

```
ForAll(
    ChoicesToRecord,
    Patch(
        'Update Mate Data',
        LookUp(
            'Update Mate Data',
            'Asset No.'= ThisRecord.ID
        ),
        {'Decom Status':ThisRecord.Choice}
    )
)
```

however when run it creates an error in the lookup portion of the code saying:

[image: Code Error]

Comment: Replace `'Asset No.'` with `ID`